# Frequency spectrum and histogram of white noise

Tags: fourier-transform, noise

I haven't been able to find any images with, so here goes:

In the frequency/Fourier spectrum, how does white noise look like ? Is that just random dots all over the place, making it very hard to filter out ?

And the same with the histogram, how does it look ? Is it just a flat line, containing more or less the same amount of intensities in your intensity range (Fx 0-255 for 8 bit).

And the last thing, is white noise gaussian distributed ?

Answer (score 2):

> is white noise gaussian distributed ?

Do you mean if the amplitude is gaussian distributed? Not necesarily. If it is, then it is properly called gaussian white noise.

> In the frequency/Fourier spectrum, how does white noise look like ?

Ideally, over an infinite time interval, it will look as a flat line, because, by definition, it has the same spectral energy at every frequency.

> And the same with the histogram, how does it look ?

Do you mean the amplitude histogram? No, lower amplitudes will be much more common than higher ones. If it is a gaussian white noise, the histogram will obviously draw a gaussian bell.

Comment: Okay, so there is a difference between gaussian white noise, and white noise ? I really didn't think so :/
Does that mean, that you can filter out gaussian white noise to some extent, but true white noise is pretty much impossible, or can you just remove the flate line in the Fourier spectrum, and get an okay white noise reduction ?

Comment: @DenverDang: White noise is noise with a flat spectral power density. Gaussian noise is noise with a Gaussian amplitude distribution. One does not imply the other. But I don't think you can completely filter out white noise without affecting the quality of the original signal.

Comment: Isn't a gaussian-distributed noise a colored noise? Doesn't it have a frequency with maximum amplitude (i.e. expected value of that gaussian)?

Comment: Shot noise is an example that is not Gaussian distributed and its spectrum is white.

Comment: @Ruslan: No, the gaussian noise refers to the amplitude distribution in time domain, while _color_ describes the noise in frequency domain.